# Run make file in subdirectory using shell script

Tags: shell, makefile

I need to run `make file_name` command in a subdirectory using shell
script and then `cd ..` out of that subdirectory and run the remaining commands in the main directory.

Comment: And what prevents you from doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `make` from the parent directory without switching to the subdirectory first:

```sh
make -C subdir file_name
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you know that your `make` is GNU make.  Not all versions of make support the `-C` option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the script is initially running in "the main directory", just cd to the subdir in a subshell.  eg

```
#!/bin/sh

# do stuff in main directory
( cd subdir; make file_name ) # use a subshell 
# now run more commands in the main directory
```

You can also use `pushd` and `popd`, or try storing `$(pwd)`, or just use `cd ..`, but the subshell is usually the cleanest solution.